# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment when inputting a certain number, but not for all other cases

Tags: python, list, function, loops

So I have a code used to calculate Kaprekar's Constant and the number of iterations it takes to reach the constant. When I input any number other than a repdigit (where all digits are the same) the code works. However when I input a repdigit, such as 7777, I get an error message (see title) and the code breaks.

Any help is appreciated!

```
# take user input
# if number has less than 4 digits, add leading zeroes
# make number a str and convert to two lists
# one list will be sorted in descending order and the other in ascending
# subtract smaller from bigger
# repeat step 2 until you reach 6174
# use loops

### DEFINE A FUNCTION ###
def k_c(n):
    num_list = [n]
    ### WHILE LOOP TO ADD LEADING ZEROS IF NEEDED ###
    while len(n) != 4:
        n = "0" + n

    d_list = list(n)
    d_list.sort(reverse=True)  # converts to descending list
    a_list = list(n)
    a_list.sort()  # converts to ascending list
    d_num = []
    a_num = []
    ### CONVERT TO INT ###
    for i in d_list:
        d_num.append(int(i))
    for i in a_list:
        a_num.append(int(i))
    d_num = "".join(d_list)
    a_num = "".join(a_list)
    d_num = int(d_num)
    a_num = int(a_num)

    if a_num > d_num:
        new_num = a_num - d_num
        num_list.append(new_num)
    elif d_num > a_num:
        new_num = d_num - a_num
        num_list.append(new_num)

    count = 1

    if len(str(new_num)) != 4:
        new_num = "0" + str(new_num)

    while new_num != 6174:  # will repeat until 6174 is reached
        ### SEPARATE INTO 2 LISTS ###
        d_list = list(str(new_num))
        d_list.sort(reverse=True)  # converts to descending list
        a_list = list(str(new_num))
        a_list.sort()  # converts to ascending list
        d_num = []
        a_num = []
        for i in d_list:
            d_num.append(int(i))
        for i in a_list:
            a_num.append(int(i))
        d_num = "".join(d_list)
        a_num = "".join(a_list)
        d_num = int(d_num)
        a_num = int(a_num)

        ### SUBTRACT SMALLER LIST NUMBER FROM LARGER LIST NUMBER ###
        if a_num > d_num:
            new_num = a_num - d_num
            num_list.append(new_num)
            count += 1
        elif d_num > a_num:
            new_num = d_num - a_num
            num_list.append(new_num)
            count += 1
    return num_list, count


num = input("Enter a four-digit integer: ")
k_numbers, iterations = k_c(num)  # establishing variables

for i in range((len(k_numbers))):  # lopping through each new number used to calculate Kaprekar's constant
    if i != (len(k_numbers) - 1):
        print(k_numbers[i], end=" > ")
    else:
        print(k_numbers[i])

print(f"{num} reaches 6174 via Kaprekar's routine in {iterations} iterations")
```

Comment: You didn't include the full error message, which would indicate *which* variable was undefined (very important) and what line it was used on (also very important)...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the variable "new_num" on line 61

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the *only* bug in this code, but this section:

```
    if a_num > d_num:
        new_num = a_num - d_num
        num_list.append(new_num)
    elif d_num > a_num:
        new_num = d_num - a_num
        num_list.append(new_num)
```

will clearly not initialize `new_num` if `a_num == d_num`.  That will in turn produce an `UnboundLocalError` on the following lines where you reference `new_num`.

You could fix this by making the `elif` an `else` (that will just set `new_num = 0` when the numbers are the same), but it would be even easier to simply use `abs` to take the absolute value of the difference:

```
    new_num = abs(a_num - d_num)
    num_list.append(new_num)
```

For what it's worth, the entire `k_c` function can be written much more simply as:

```
def k_c(n: str) -> tuple[list[str], int]:
    n = n.ljust(4, '0')
    if n == '6174':
        return [n], 0
    
    num_list, count = k_c(str(abs(
        int(''.join(sorted(n))) - int(''.join(sorted(n, reverse=True)))
    )))
    return [n] + num_list, count + 1
```

or, iteratively:

```
def k_c(n: str) -> tuple[list[str], int]:
    nums = [n.ljust(4, '0')]
    while nums[-1] != '6174':
        nums.append(
            str(abs(
                int(''.join(sorted(nums[-1])))
                - int(''.join(sorted(nums[-1], reverse=True)))
            )).ljust(4, '0')
        )
    return nums, len(nums) - 1
```

Note that a number like `7777` will never converge on a solution because it will become `0000` on the first iteration and then stay at `0000`.  In the recursive solution, this results in a `RecursionError` after the recursion depth is exceeded, and in the iterative solution, the program will just loop forever until you kill it manually.